# How to use Redis cache in Web Api with repository

Tags: asp.net-web-api, redis

I am new in Redis cache implementation and got in simple example with `getstring` from Redis Cache which is working fine. But Same time I didnt get any idea about Set and get list values through Redis.

I have Using Provider and Repository. Please help me how to further proceed...

```
 public List<Article> GetArticleListBySectionName(string sectionName, int RegionId, int Count, int CacheTime, string cacheKey, bool cacheEnable = false, string expiryInMinutes = "NoExpiry")
    {
        {
            cacheKey = GetCacheKey(cacheKey, Convert.ToString(sectionName));
            List<Article> _article = _cacheProxy.Get<List<Article>>(cacheKey);
            if (_article != null)
            {
                _article = _articleRepositary.GetArticleListBySectionName(sectionName, RegionId, Count, CacheTime);
                _cacheProxy.Store<List<Article>>(_article, cacheKey, expiryInMinutes);
            }
            return _article;
        }
    }
```

Here `_cacheProxy.Get` and `_cacheProxy.Store` getting `null` values..While executing this, I ll getting error page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Inject the dependencies
2. Add the below line in WebApiConfig

   `config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(Bootstrapper.Initialise(DIContainer.Initialise()));`
3. Add the Redis Endpoint that is `127.0.0.1:6379`